# how to convert .docx to html using apache poi which also includes images

Tags: java, html, apache, apache-poi, docx

How to convert .docx to html in which I can also have resume, for .doc my code is working and I can see the images in the html but when I convert .docx to .html and if image is there in .docx document, image is not appearing

Comment: Maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/30831702/180100

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the document as webpage and under tool section. Select web option and under browser select Internet Explorer 6 or later.